# how to create a date field call lead closed date when lead status equals to Qualified, Disqualified, Unqualified?

Tags: leads

I want to create a customize field called lead closed date to show the date when lead status changed to qualified, disaqulified or unqualified.

Anyone helps?

Comment: Create a Formula field called lead closed date and based on the status of lead populate the date in the formula field.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a trigger onUpdate, check if the status has changed to those values, and save the current date in the new field.